# Pages taking long time to load Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to do some automations with Selenium VBA but the webpages are taking a long time loading compared to when I load it with regularly with Chrome. I read somewhere on here to set the `"pageLoadStrategy"` to `"none"` but that didn't really do much. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Add more details

Comment: try setting this in chrome options: options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");  You might also try using an existing profile when launching.

Comment: How would the implementation work for that? I have ````With Driver /t .setCapability "pageLoadStrategy", "none"```` there isnt an .addArgument method